# Cpp program is to create arrays, looking to improve the code

Tags: c++, arrays, list, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

This program is to create two arrays: a Library that is 1024 lines deep and a List that is 128 lines deep. The contents of each line for both arrays will be chars between 2MB to 3MB in length (randomly assigned by program). The user will be prompted to type in a random word and the program will search for all instances of that word in the List. The line(s) that contain the word will remain in the list, those that do not contain the word will be ejected from List and be reinitialized at the bottom of the Library. Simultaneously, the List will be truncated and the upper-most lines of the Library will be added to the empty lines of the List. I added comments where I'm having difficulties with my code.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

// Constants used to create depth and width of recent_list and Library
const int recentList_Size = 128, library_Size = 1024; // Number of 'lines' in the 
// recent_list and Library
// Used to create variable sizes of chars
const int btm = 2000000, top = 3000000; 
// Was told to use power of 2s, but a quick cout of 2^21 gives 23 not 2M

// Create pointers for recent_list and Library
struct Arrays {
    char* recent[recentList_Size];
    char* library[library_Size];
};

// Method to generate 26 CAPITAL letters using ascii value
inline char random_letter() {
    return char('A' + rand() % 26);
}

// Build the array
// Was told to check memory?
void initArrays(Arrays& o) {
    for (int i = 0; i < recentList_Size; i++) // Build recent_list vertically
    {
        int sz = rand() % (top - btm + 1) + btm;  // Used to randomly generate array sized between 2MB and 3MB
        o.recent[i] = new char[sz + 1];       // Dynamically allocate memory to a pointer based on list size
        for (int j = 0; j < sz; j++)
            o.recent[i][j] = random_letter(); // Fill horizontal array with randomly generated alphabet characters 
        o.recent[i][sz] = '\0';
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < library_Size; i++)    // Build Library (simialr method as the above)
    {
        int sz = rand() % (top - btm + 1) + btm;
        o.library[i] = new char[sz + 1];
        for (int j = 0; j < sz; j++)
            o.library[i][j] = random_letter();
        o.library[i][sz] = '\0';
    }
}

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    Arrays a;
    initArrays(a);
    int input;

    // Prompt for user
    cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << " Press 1 to search the Recent List for a word " << endl;
    cout << " Press 2 to exit the program" << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cin >> input;

    // catch if input not within bounds
    while (input != 1 && input != 2)
    {
        cout << "-------- Please ONLY press 1 or 2 ---------" << endl;
        cout << " Press 1 to search the Recent List for a word " << endl;
        cout << " Press 2 to exit the program" << endl;
        cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cin >> input;
    }

    while (input != 2)
    {
            cout << "Enter a word to search for in the recent_list: ";

            char* search_word = new(char[16]); // 15 letter word, 16 character of \0 to mark the end of the string
                                               // Dynamic memory needed for comparison
            cin >> search_word;
            while (cin.get() != '\n') continue; // FLush buffer

            // Array of booleans that will match the recent_List length, where we are going to mark if the array has 
            // the word we are looking for.
            bool words_found_at[recentList_Size] = { false };

            // Go through each array of letters and find the matching word
            // Keep count of instances where word is and is not found in each array of letters
            int words_found = 0;
            int words_not_found = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < recentList_Size; i++) {
                // C++ function strstr used to compare chars of array to char inputted 
                if (strstr(a.recent[i], search_word) != NULL) {
                    words_found++;            // Increment counter
                    words_found_at[i] = true; // Tab when word is found (original code)
                }
            }
            words_not_found = recentList_Size - words_found;

            cout << search_word << " found in " << words_found << " arrays " << endl;
            cout << words_not_found << " arrays were ejected " << endl;

            if (words_found != 0) {
                // "Move" the arrays where the word was not found to a recent_list temp
                char** recent_list_move = new char* [words_not_found];
                for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < recentList_Size; i++) {
                    // instances in char array where word was not found
                    if (words_found_at[i] == false) {
                        recent_list_move[j] = a.recent[i]; // create temp array of chars w/o word(s) based on position
                        j++;
                    }
                }

                // Based on the num of words not found, "move" the arrays from the contents from the Library
                // to another temp array in FIFO order
                char** library_list_move = new char* [words_not_found];
                for (int i = 0; i < words_not_found; i++) {
                    library_list_move[i] = a.library[i];
                }

                // Shift Library up to maintain the FIFO order
                // j is used for the position of array after the top 'n' array(s) have been moved to the recent_list
                for (int i = 0, j = words_not_found; i < library_Size; i++, j++) {
                    if (j < 15)
                    {
                        a.library[i] = a.library[j];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        a.library[i] = NULL; // j goes out of bounds of array when i = 12
                    }
                }

                // "Move" arrays of words from recent_list temp to the Library
                // (library_Size - words_not_found) used to place recent_list temp contents at the bottom of Library
                for (int i = library_Size - words_not_found, j = 0; i < library_Size; i++, j++) {
                    a.library[i] = recent_list_move[j];
                }

                // Find first index where word(s) have not been found, since that is the index
                // Keeps count of how many spaces need to be filled
                int shift_starts_at = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < recentList_Size; i++) {
                    if (words_found_at[i] == false) {
                        shift_starts_at = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Truncate recent_list up 
                for (int i = shift_starts_at, j = shift_starts_at; i < recentList_Size; i++) {
                    if (words_found_at[i] == true) {
                        a.recent[j] = a.recent[i];
                        j++;
                    }
                }

                // Fill in the recent_list with contents from library based on count
                // 'i' will be the starting position of the recent_list after truncation
                for (int i = recentList_Size - words_not_found, j = 0; i < recentList_Size; i++, j++) {
                    a.recent[i] = library_list_move[j];
                }
            }

        // Prompt for user
        cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << " Press 1 to search the Recent List for a word " << endl;
        cout << " Press 2 to exit the program" << endl;
        cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cin >> input;

        while (input != 1 && input != 2 && input != 3)
        {
            cout << "---------Please press only 1, 2 or 3---------" << endl;
            cout << " Press 1 to search the Recent List for a word" << endl;
            cout << " Press 2 to exit the program" << endl;
            cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
            cin >> input;
        }

    }
// Recommended to de-allocate memory before exiting but unsure how to do so
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"I'm getting an exception thrown in the print_list() function when it runs and I search a char."* - so... when do you plan on telling people here on stackoverflow about the exception contents?

Comment: Values like 0xFDFDFDFD are typically found in DEBUG Builds for uninitialized variables. Since this one is an access violation, the uninitialized variable is probably a pointer. So, either `Arrays *a` is uninitialized, or some `a->recent[i]` or `a->library[i]` is uninitialized. You should check (debug, print, ...) `a` (unlikely culprit) and all those pointer values to find the offending index (likely culprit). Then find out, WHY there is some uninitialized index.